# Collision Bit Mask Hero passes right through EVERY thing, even the Ground

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicscontact

I am trying to avoid collisions between Hero and Coins, but not between Hero and Grass Ground. As soon as I apply a Collision Bit Mask to Hero, my Hero passes right through EVERY thing. I want it to pass through the Coins but not through the Grass Ground. Here is the code, any ideas?

```
let HEROCATEGORY: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1;
let GROUNDCATEGORY: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2;
let FIRECATEGORY: UInt32 = 0x1 << 3;
let COINCATEGORY: UInt32 = 0x1 << 4;
let NUMBERCATEGORY: UInt32 = 0x1 << 5;

heroSprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = HEROCATEGORY;
heroSprite.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0x10000000;
heroSprite.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = GROUNDCATEGORY | FIRECATEGORY | COINCATEGORY | NUMBERCATEGORY;

grassGround.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = GROUNDCATEGORY;
grassGround.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0x01000000;

coinSprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = COINCATEGORY;
coinSprite.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = HEROCATEGORY;
coinSprite.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0x10000000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If hero has to detect collision with only the ground, then hero's collission bit mask should be

```
heroSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = GROUNDCATEGORY
```

To detect collision with ground and something else, you should use the **OR `|` operator** to combine both `categoryBitMasks`

```
 heroSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = GROUNDCATEGORY | SOMETHINGCATEGORY
```

The `contactTestBitMask` is used to get a callback on contact between the two bodies. We get a callback when both objects share the same space. It doesn't handle collisions.

I think what you need is contact detection with fire and coins and collision detection with ground. So just set collision bit mask of `heroSprite` to `GROUNDCATEGORY` like in my first code snippet.

```
let HEROCATEGORY: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
let GROUNDCATEGORY: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
let FIRECATEGORY: UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
let COINCATEGORY: UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
let NUMBERCATEGORY: UInt32 = 0x1 << 5

heroSprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = HEROCATEGORY
heroSprite.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = GROUNDCATEGORY // changed
heroSprite.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = GROUNDCATEGORY | FIRECATEGORY | COINCATEGORY | NUMBERCATEGORY

grassGround.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = GROUNDCATEGORY
grassGround.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = HEROCATEGORY

coinSprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = COINCATEGORY
coinSprite.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = HEROCATEGORY
```